# Apache httpd.conf VirtualHost: Attach to the same IP but different port (non standard)

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I have a webserver with 2 domains (already attached to a folder), I want my global server configuration, which basically using "/var/www/html" as default document root, to have ANOTHER folder for ANOTHER user, based on just different port (I have read that it is possible in Apache site).

Follow is the cite from apache site:

> Each Virtual Host must correspond to a different IP address, different port number, or a different host name for the server, in the former case the server machine must be configured to accept IP packets for multiple addresses. (If the machine does not have multiple network interfaces, then this can be accomplished with the ifconfig alias command -- if your OS supports it).

So my IP is XX.XX.XX.XX and server configuration has the line "listen 443" (I am running by default on https), I did the following:

```
listen 19758 https
<VirtualHost XX.XX.XX.XX:19785>
    ServerName XX.XX.XX.XX:19785
    DocumentRoot "/the/path/to/the/user/directory/public_html"
    <Directory "/the/path/to/the/user/directory/public_html">
        AllowOverride none
        Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <IfModule mpm_itk.c>
        AssignUserID EFX EFX
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

I opened the port in the iptables, and made sure it is opened.
However: When I open the browser and typing "XX.XX.XX.XX:19785", it just timeouts without giving me the page (index.htm) that sits in the desired directory.

Note: This user has no associated domain, and will never has one. 
The server is running with 2 other domains that have associated folders, I don't want to mix with them.

What I am doing wrong?

The main idea is to be able to enter from the browser to that directory as that user, and not as "nobody" (the default user of the server in the configuration file).

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: First try to test without https, debug will be easy with it. and check answer in this link he enabled virtual host on different port with https https://superuser.com/questions/1151196/apache-2-with-ssl-virtual-host-on-different-port-8080-or-8081-in-linux

Comment: The link above contain domain for the virtual host. If I don't have domain, I want to use the server IP as the host, with different port - the :443 and :80 that I have working fine. But in addition to those, I want also 19785 which will be https. Can it be that it collide with the 443? I checked "httpd -S" the VirtualHost exists, and "fuser -va 19785/tcp" and it shows "httpd" is listening... I will try without https too

Comment: I have tried without https, not working either...